# QueryWithRowMapperDelegate performance issue - alternative solutions

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm returning a result set with QueryWithRowMapperDelegate and mapping columns returned to different fields in a class. The below code snippet is very similar to what my code is. This works fine with small amounts of rows returned but when my ResultSet consists of 3400+ rows, it takes a long time to iterate through it.  Is this simply a limitation of using this method?

Any alternative solutions?

```
List<Customer> customers = Ado.AdoTemplate.QueryWithRowMapperDelegate<Customer>(CommandType.Text, cmdText,
new RowMapperDelegate<Customer>((reader, rowNum) =>
{
   Customer customer = new Customer();
   customer.Address = reader.GetString(0, string.Empty);
   customer.City = reader.GetString(1, string.Empty);
   customer.CompanyName = reader.GetString(2, string.Empty);
   customer.ContactName = reader.GetString(3, string.Empty);
   customer.ContactTitle = reader.GetString(4, string.Empty);
   customer.Country = reader.GetString(5, string.Empty);
   customer.Fax = reader.GetString(6, string.Empty);
   customer.Id = reader.GetString(7, string.Empty);
   customer.Phone = reader.GetString(8, string.Empty);
   customer.PostalCode = reader.GetString(9, string.Empty);
   customer.Region = reader.GetString(10, string.Empty);
   return customer;
})).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ResultSetExtractorDelegate<Customer>` is a Delegate, therefor it is not precompiled. Write a method with the same functionality and pass it to `QueryWithRowMapperDelegate`.
In your Customer class:

```
            public static Customer GetFromRecord(IDataReader reader, int rownum)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.Address = reader.GetString(0, string.Empty);
            customer.City = reader.GetString(1, string.Empty);
            customer.CompanyName = reader.GetString(2, string.Empty);
            customer.ContactName = reader.GetString(3, string.Empty);
            customer.ContactTitle = reader.GetString(4, string.Empty);
            customer.Country = reader.GetString(5, string.Empty);
            customer.Fax = reader.GetString(6, string.Empty);
            customer.Id = reader.GetString(7, string.Empty);
            customer.Phone = reader.GetString(8, string.Empty);
            customer.PostalCode = reader.GetString(9, string.Empty);
            customer.Region = reader.GetString(10, string.Empty);
            return customer;
        }
```

and

```
List<Customer> customers = Ado.AdoTemplate.QueryWithRowMapperDelegate<Customer>(CommandType.Text, cmdText, Customer.GetFromRecord).ToList();
```

It should give the same result in much less time.

Regards,
Peter